# Restrict Dates in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

I have a condition like don't let the user apply for the dates been already in database. I have a dates Start_date->01-01-2017 & end_date->05-01-2017 in database. when the user comes with following dates, i have to show error message

1. startDate-> 05-01-2017 EndDate->06-01-2017
2. StartDate->31-12-2016 endaDate-> 01-01-2017
3. StartDate->31-12-2016 endDate ->06-01-2017
4. StartDate->02-01-2017 endDate ->02-01-2017
5. StartDate->04-01-2017 endDate->06-01-2017

i have tried with this query

```
SELECT * from leave_request_tbl l 
where leave_start_date between '2017-01-01' and '2017-01-05'
and leave_end_date between '2017-01-01'
and '2017-01-05'
order by user_id;
```

Am not able to satisfy my condition, how do get it

Thanks in advance

Comment: The proper format for a date constant is `'2017-01-05'`.

Comment: Wrong `order by user_id=2` Right `AND user_id = 2 ORDER BY user_id`

Comment: mysql date format is YYYY-MM-DD

Comment: Are the `leave_start_date` and `leave_end_date` defined as `DATE` or `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP`? Or are they `VARCHAR()`

Comment: @RiggsFolly , both was Date in my sql and Here how i will use two where condtion

Comment: Then format the date as per MYSQL requirements like `where leave_start_date between '2017-01-01' and '2017-01-05'` i.e. `YYYY-MM-DD`

Comment: @RiggsFolly  Yea , you are right, But that's not resolved my issu. am using correct format in MYSQL(YYYY-MM-DD)

Comment: You are now that you have edited the question! But you were not originally!! We can only comment on what we see!!!

Comment: You still have not fixed the `ORDER BY` error

Comment: am not facing ORDER By error . I want check my all conditions which i have mentioned in my ques. Using this query am able to check 1,2 and 4. but rest of the 3 and 5 i can't make it.....this is query now  ---- SELECT * from ems.leave_request_tbl l where leave_start_date <='2017-01-01' and leave_start_date <='2017-01-05' and  user_id=2 ;

Answer (score 1):

If you are checking user's (id=2) input `startDate-> 05-01-2017 EndDate->06-01-2017` then the rows which overlap the user provided interval:

```
select * 
from leave_request_tbl l 
where leave_start_date <= '2017-01-06' 
and leave_end_date >= '2017-01-05'
and user_id=2 
order by leave_start_date ;
```

Intervals i1 and i2 overlap if `i1.start <= i2.end  and i2.start <= i1.end`

Comment: It doesn't satisfy my 2,3,4 conditions. but i have completed in java code. Thanks anyway..